# Error when adding a translation. (Package R does not exist)

Tags: android

After the change:
`bind.totalRef.setText("Total Refe : "+pref.getInt(pref.successRef) ); bind.pendingRef.setText("Pending Refer : "+pref.getInt(pref.pendingRef) );`

For:

`bind.totalRef.setText(getString(R.string.ilosc_poleconych) + " : " +pref.getInt(pref.successRef) ); bind.pendingRef.setText(getString(R.string.oczekujacych_poleconych) + " : " +pref.getInt(pref.pendingRef) );`

And adding to the strings.xml file:

`<string name="ilosc_poleconych">Total Refer</string> <string name="oczekujacych_poleconych">Pending Refer</string>`

An error message appears:

`package R does not exist bind.totalRef.setText(getString(R.string.ilosc_poleconych) + " : " +pref.getInt(pref.successRef) ); ^`
`package R does not exist bind.pendingRef.setText(getString(R.string.oczekujacych_poleconych) + " : " +pref.getInt(pref.pendingRef) ); ^`

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Clean Project,
Rebuild Project,
Sync Project with Gradle
Invalidate Cane -> Clear file.., Clear VCS.., Delete embeddet...

did not help.

Comment: Is Java/Kotlin code in the same Module of strings.xml?

Comment: Is the R in R.string.ocz... coloured in red in android studio's editor?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same project.
Yes, R is in the red.